# Как логгировать в базу данных postgresql

Tags: java, postgresql

Как можно реализовать транзакции в базу данных наподобие логгирования? Например, пользователь авторизируется и это сразу пишется в таблицу.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48104368/postgresql-trigger-on-user-logon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ найден, Hibernate за меня всё делает, создал сущность и теперь просто каждое действие записываю в базу данных log:

```
Log log = new Log();
log.setWho("vasya");
log.setEvent("user banned");
logRepository.save(log);
```